# How to use entity full path instead relative path

Tags: 8

Following Drupal entity used in editor and called in JSON API in body field.

```
<drupal-entity alt="Blog Post Image" data-align="center" data-embed-button="media_browser" data-entity-embed-display="media_image" data-entity-embed-display-settings="{&quot;image_style&quot;:&quot;&quot;,&quot;image_link&quot;:&quot;&quot;}" data-entity-type="media" data-entity-uuid="111f85db-99f7-4430-aa9b-ad644be8bc23" data-langcode="en" title="Blog Post Image"></drupal-entity>
```

Json Response:

```
[{
    "title": "Use Drupal img src with full url ?",
    "body": "Here is image which came with /relative-path.jpg, <img src=\u0022\/sites\/default\/files\/2019-12\/image28-8fc299e2b382af7f3d188613d4b66933.jpg\u0022 /> "
}]
```

Is there any setting in Drupal admin panel to set full eg: http://cms-api.local/sites/default/files/2019-12/image28.jpg instead `/sites/default/files/2019-12/image28.jpg`

Details:

- Drupal domain: cms-api.local
- Frontend API: project.local:8000/

Comment: The Pathologic module may fix this.  The URLs in the body look like they were entered with relative URLs.  Pathologic is designed to normalize URL entered by people as an input filter.  This may or may not work with the jsonapi but it seems like a good place to start.

Comment: it's will conflict with local and pro envs, here is quick hack https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59413727/gatsby-javascript-replace-images-src-from-api-response